# Laravel 5.5. - Create a Collection from two collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I have two different collections from 2 eloquent requests ($training_sessions & $users_count)

My first collection is giving me information for training sessions :

```
2 => {#464 ▼
  +"date": "2018-02-24"
  +"id": 4
  +"debutsession": "13:30:00"
  +"finsession": "17:00:00"
  +"creneau": "13:30:00 - 17:00:00"
  +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
  +"nom": "MYNAME"
  +"prenom": "MYSURNAME"
  +"salle": "ROOM NAME "
  +"sessions": "SESSION NAME"
```

And i have a second Collection which gives me a count of users that will participate to the session

```
0 => {#564 ▼
  +"id": 2
  +"userscount": 4
}
1 => {#562 ▼
  +"id": 3
  +"userscount": 1
}
```

I tried to find out which method would allow me to create a single collection which would give me for each training session the number of attendees i get from the second collection (field userscount)

For example for id = 2:

```
2 => {#464 ▼
  +"date": "2018-02-24"
  +"id": 2
  +"debutsession": "13:30:00"
  +"finsession": "17:00:00"
  +"creneau": "13:30:00 - 17:00:00"
  +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
  +"nom": "MYNAME"
  +"prenom": "MYSURNAME"
  +"salle": "ROOM NAME "
  +"sessions": "SESSION NAME"
  +"userscount": 1
}
```

And for a session without any attendee i would have :

```
2 => {#464 ▼
  +"date": "2018-02-24"
  +"id": 2
  +"debutsession": "13:30:00"
  +"finsession": "17:00:00"
  +"creneau": "13:30:00 - 17:00:00"
  +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
  +"nom": "MYNAME"
  +"prenom": "MYSURNAME"
  +"salle": "ROOM NAME "
  +"sessions": "SESSION NAME"
  +"userscount": 0
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you give more details what do you want exactly ?

Comment: i want to create a Collection with has a commun key in both Collections ... my 2 collections have an "id" key ... For each items of my first collection i want to add usercount key/ value  from the second Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to change the second collection (**usercounts**) so that it's indexed by user IDs and we can easily access **userscount** by **ID**:

```
$usercounts = $usercounts->keyBy('id');
```

Secondly, you need to process the first collection and add **usercount** property:

```
$firstCollection->each(function($record) use ($usercounts) {
  if($usercounts->has($record['id'])) {
    $record['usercount'] = $usercounts[$record['id']]['usercount'];
  } else {
    $record['usercount'] = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: It works partially ... but it was helpful anyway !  in fact i have an error message because i have an object an not an array ... I replaced  has($record['id']) by has($record->id)...